# How can I number this type of relationship?

Tags: numbering, equation-number

[image]

numbering this code

```
\begin{‎align‎}‎‎
‎(P4)‎\left\{‎ \begin{array}{l}
   ‎\max\sum_{i=1}^{m}‎w‎_{‎i}‎(1-z_i)‎‎\\
    \mathrm{s}.\mathrm{‎t}‎:‎
    \begin{‎‎array‎}{|‎r‎}‎‎
          ‎log(e_i)\geq \sum_{j\in J^{<‎1‎}_{i}‎}‎log(1-p_{ij}x_j)‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{2‎.2‎cm}‎‎~~‎i=1,‎\ldots, ‎m‎\\
        ‎z_{i}\geq e_i-\sum_{j\in J^{=‎1‎}_{‎i}‎}‎x_j‎‎‎‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{‎4‎‎.2‎cm}‎‎~~‎i=1,‎\ldots, ‎m‎‎\\‎
        \sum_{‎j=1‎}^{n}‎C‎_j ‎x_j\leq ‎B‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{‎7‎‎‎.2‎cm}‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎
        \sum{k\in S_j}x_k‎\leq M(1-x_j)‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{‎3‎‎.‎4‎‎cm}‎‎~~‎j‎=1,‎\ldots, ‎n\\‎
      ‎‎  ‎‎x\in\{0,1\}^{‎n}‎‎‎‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{‎5‎.‎6‎‎cm}‎‎~~‎j=1,‎\ldots, ‎n‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎
      z_i\geq ‎0‎‎‎~‎‎\hspace*{‎6‎‎.‎4‎‎‎cm}‎‎~~‎i=1,‎\ldots, ‎m‎
    \end{‎‎array‎}‎‎
    \right.
  \end{array} ‎\right.‎‎
‎\end‎{‎align‎}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please; I want to number this relationship so that I can refer to each relationship.  I used verity of usepackage but they didn't work .

Comment: What does "P1" stand for? Is it some kind of equation number?